# How to set up a good motion blur and shutter speed

Tags: rendering, motion-blur, settings

So here's my problem,
I recently moved on Blender, and I'm currently learning it (I mean, I know how to animate and stuff, but I need to learn it using Blender).
So, I would like to get a good render setting using with 24fps project. So basically, I would like to get the same result shown on this video:

https://vimeo.com/187697454

Everything is perfect, the shutter speed, everything looks professional in my opinion, and I just really like the settings she set up here!

Is anyone know how to get that, please

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect as an answer? That we look at the video and know the exact settings of the motion blur? We can only try to determine the rotation speed and then experimenting until it looks similar - but it would still not be perfectly the same (unless she simply used the default settings and there is nothing to change for the motion blur). The best would be to contact her or ask in the comments there which settings she used...

Comment: Well, I'm just asking something similar, I just don't know how blender work with render, and yeah, I tried to contact her, but no answer :/

Comment: If you don't know how to render in Blender or to render with motion blur, have you tried searching for tutorials on motion blur or at least the basics of Blender? Because it is always also a matter of taste what "good" motion blur is. If you have how to get any kind of motion blur, well the simple answer is enable _Motion Blur_ in the render setttings... then play with the settings until you like what you see.

Comment: Yeah, I already saw tutorials, but yeah, you're right, I should render the same video with multiple settings to see what's the best. Thank you for helping too ^^

Comment: Hi :). Motion blur and optimal shutterspeed is more about filmmaking than Blender. By default Blender gives you the 0.5 shutter - a gold standard in filmmaking

Comment: Hi all - I came to this from a search, so if anyone's looking for the same, a good rule of thumb is increasing Motion Blur > Shutter Speed will give you more blur, and decreasing it gives less.